# Laravel "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219"

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, laravel-5

I'm just wondering right now why this particular table I am interacting with the database returns an error like the above subject where in fact I am just using the same mechanism from other table. I am refering to my table "Inventory". My store method just simply returns an error stated in the subject above and I have checked all the parameters in controller and in my model and it seems there is no error. Can somebody help me spot the error here. Please help. Here are my codes.

```
InventoryController.php

public function store( Request $request ){

            $prod_ids = $request['product_ids'];
            $purchase_order_ids = $request['purchase_order_ids'];
            $purchase_ids = $request['purchase_ids'];
            $quantity = $request['purchaseQuantity'];

            for($i = 0; $i < count($prod_ids); $i++){

                Inventory::create([
                                        'product_id' => $prod_ids[$i],
                                        'purchase_order_id' =>  $purchase_order_ids[$i],
                                        'purchase_id' => $purchase_ids[$i],
                                        'quantity' => $quantity[$i]

                                 ]);

            }

            return json_encode(array('notify' => "Success"));

}
```

My model => Inventory.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Inventory;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inventory extends Model
{
protected $fillable =
['product_id','purchase_order_id','purchase_id','quantity'];
}
```

My Javascript:

```
$("#purchase_toInventoryID").click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();

    var array_prodID = <?php echo json_encode(isset($array_prodID) ? $array_prodID : 0); ?>;
    var array_poID = <?php echo json_encode(isset($array_poID) ? $array_poID : 0); ?>;
    var array_purchaseID = <?php echo json_encode(isset($array_purchaseID) ? $array_purchaseID : 0); ?>;
    var array_purchaseQuantity = <?php echo json_encode(isset($array_purchaseQuantity) ? $array_purchaseQuantity : 0); ?>;


    $.post("{{ url('saveToInventory') }}", { 
            'product_ids': array_prodID, 
            'purchase_order_ids': array_poID,
            'purchase_ids':array_purchaseID,
            'purchaseQuantity': array_purchaseQuantity
       }, function(data){

        if(data.notify == "Success"){

          console.log(data.notify);

        }else{
          console.log(data.notify);
        }

      }, 'json');

  });
```

My routes.php

```
Route::post('saveToInventory', 'Inventory\InventoryController@store');
```

[image]